# Get ArrayList element by custom text indexing

Tags: java

What I'm doing is storing classes into an ArrayList and retrieve them by its index number.  But are there any list classes in Java where I can retrieve a list element by, lets say, its name?  Like this:

```
ArrayList<string> myArr = new ArrayList<string>();
myArr.add( "ID_name", "String to store" );
```

ands then retrieve it by:

```
myArr.get( "ID_name" );
```

Also, are there any other alternatives to ArrayList?  I need a list class to be optimized for:

- Random access
- Only need to push items into the list
- Never need to delete anything from the list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you want to store is key-value pairs, and don't care about iteration order,  I think you might like the HashMap class:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "bar");
String bar = map.get("foo"); // bar is "bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), so it will preserve the order, but you can extract elements by key as in regular map. Though you won't be able to extract entries by index.

Answer (score 2):

An ArrayList is just that: an array. If you want to access values by something else than their indices, look for the various implementations of the Map interface (such as HashMap).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Map<String, String>`. In such structure, an element is added with a key. So you can get the element through the key:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("id", "string");
String s = map.get("id"); // s will be equals to "string".
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other people have mentioned, a HashMap is probably what you want if you don't care about iteration order.

If you do, you can use a [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html), which is really a HashMap bolted onto an LinkedList, giving you the best of both worlds: fast random access and preservation of iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hashmap.  You can add elements to a hashmap in much the same way as an arraylist.  Also, you can create a set of keys ( 1 elements in the set per (key, value) pair)).  You can then iterate over the set of keys.